How I show dropdown select List<String> on chip widgets
When the user selects the Dropdown item, it collects the list data, but I can't show it on the chip widgets.

                            Expanded(
                          child: WasteMaterialCategory(
                            wasteMatUpFn: (wasteMat) {
                              wasteMaterial = wasteMat;
                              log(wasteMaterial.length.toString());
                            },
                          ),
                        ),


Reusable Widget code

FirebaseDropdownHelper(
  onDropdownFn: (value) {
    if (wasteMaterial.contains(value)) {
      dialoghelper.removeMessage(context);
      dialoghelper.showMessage(context,
          "The material already Selected. Please choose different one");
      return;
    }

    setState(() {
      wasteMaterial.add(value);
    });
    widget.wasteMatUpFn(wasteMaterial);
  },
  dropHint: "Please select Material on Spot",
  dropLevel: "Waste Category",
  fsCollection: "wasteMaterial",
  fsField: "category",
);


helper class for getting Dropdown item

StreamBuilder(
  stream: api.fireStore.collection(widget.fsCollection).snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text("Some error Occured ${snapshot.hasError}"),
      );
    }
    List<DropdownMenuItem> impactItems = [];

    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return const Center(
        child: SizedBox(width: 30, height: 30, child: LoadingWidgets()),
      );
    } else {
      final dropSnapshot = snapshot.data?.docs.toList();
      if (dropSnapshot != null) {
        for (var dropSnapshots in dropSnapshot) {
          impactItems.add(
            DropdownMenuItem(
              value: dropSnapshots[widget.fsField],
              child: Text(dropSnapshots[widget.fsField]),
            ),
          );
        }
      }
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: DropdownButtonFormField(
          value: selectValue,
          hint: Text(
            widget.dropHint,
            style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
          ),
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.orangeAccent),
          //this line for DropDown Dialog background color or Radius
          dropdownColor: Colors.black,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),

          //Decoration refer for hint and other outer
          decoration: InputDecoration(
              label: Text(
                widget.dropLevel,
                style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
              ),
              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30))),
          items: impactItems,
          onChanged: (value) {
            widget.onDropdownFn(value);
            setState(() {
              selectValue = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      );
    }
  },
);

As the image below show, I can save the data on the List

But I can't create a chip when a new value is added to the list. Code for the chip:
                            Expanded(
                          child: ListTile(
                            title: const Text("Select Material:"),
                            trailing: wasteMaterial.isEmpty
                                ? null
                                : Row(
                                    children: [
                                      for (var wasteMat in wasteMaterial)
                                        Wrap(
                                          direction: Axis.vertical,
                                          spacing: csGap,
                                          children: [
                                            Chip(
                                              backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                                              label: Text(
                                                wasteMat,
                                              ),
                                              onDeleted: () {
                                                wasteMaterial
                                                    .remove(wasteMat);
                                              },
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                          ),
                        ),

Note: This code is on the Stateful Widget.
Any suggestions are helpful.
Thanks in advanceed
